# OS docker container: what is the difference with a VM then?

Tags: docker

What is the point of using an OS in a docker container?

In the docker repository, you find an Ubuntu docker image: https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/
I thought Docker was more at the "app" level.

What is then the differences between an Ubuntu docker container and an Ubuntu Virtual Machine?
If you have an entire OS in a docker container, isn't it pointless to use Docker then?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are lacking basic Docker concepts. It's a completely different thing.

The first thing you need to know is Docker's philosophy : run **one process** isolated in a container. You won't run an OS in a Docker container, you will run a process inside a container with a root filesystem content based on a linux distribution of your choosing. Ubuntu is a choice among others.

Now you should wonder how is it possible to get a process runing inside a linux base image different from the linux distribution your host is running with. For an OS to run you basically need :

- A boot filesystem : contains the bootloader and the kernel that will reside in memory once loaded. We don't care about this in the case of Docker containers because the kernel is shared with the host and is the common part between all linux distributions.
- A root filesystem : contains the filesystem structure. It may be different from one linux distribution to another. It's read-only until the boot sequence has finished.

Docker uses UnionFS to manage layers of disk blocks inside a container so you can pile them.

Behind the scenes, it uses an union mount which allows multiple filesystems to be mounted at the same time, appearing like a whole virtual one. It in fact drops the base image layer as read-write mode on top of the base root filesystem in read-only mode.

Here you have a pile of disk blocks layered in a way that the linux distribution the base image comes from would contain the same filesystem once installed in a real host, but it's inside a container this time.

The last thing lacking now is : how do you run this thing isolated ?

The answer is : namespaces. I won't go into the details here because it would deviate a bit from the original question. But what you need to know is that since kernel 2.4.19, namespaces of various kinds have appeared along the years. Currently the following namespaces are available :

- IPC : IPC namespace (interprocess communications)
- MNT : mount namespace
- NET : network namespace
- PID : pid namespace
- USER : user namespace (uid)
- UTS : UTS namespace (hostnames)

Namespaces are isolated structures inside the kernel that allow processes to run with a particular environment. For instance MNT namespace will be the key feature to get a process running in the base image root filesystem specificities. NET namespace will be another key feature for a container to have specific network interfaces in order to communicate with the docker bridge etc.

So, yes, the main purpose of all of this is to run an application isolated, ship it from your local environment to production easily with inside a box called container.

It would be a good idea to read [docker's documentation](http://docs.docker.com/introduction/understanding-docker/) before digging further into it.

Comment: Thanks, does that mean that a "Ubuntu" image like this one: https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/ makes "no sense" by itself and serve as a base for more defined container like a "nginx container"? I do not know if I make sense?

Comment: Yes you do. That's exactly what's it's used for. And usually you will hear people call them *[base images](https://docs.docker.com/terms/image/#parent-image)* for this reason.

Comment: I have gone through the documentation and there is one thing I am not sure. Let's say the size of the ubuntu image is 140Mb. Then, another image based on this image adds 10 more Mb. If I run 2 containers from this image, will each container be 150Mb and I need 300Mb of disk space OR th total size will remain 150Mb? Thanks

Comment: Wow, I just downloaded the official python image and the virtual size is 802.4 MB. It took a while to download. If I run 10 containers from it, how much space the containers will take? Thanks

Comment: @YAmikep Some images can be big due to dependencies not properly cleaned. If you start 10 containers with the same image then it doesn't mean the disk space used will be 10 times the size of the image. You donwload an image once but run it from multiple containers. Docker use copy-on-write when running multiple containers from the same image which basically means that it will share the image between containers and create a private copy of a file inside an image only if the container add/modifies it. So the actual size used is linked to the activity inside containers, not how many runs.

Comment: So if I pull the base Ubuntu image and customize that image to a few implementations, will the size of the Ubuntu base image be shared with the customized containers? Or are all commited containers atomic in a sense that they cannot share the base image after certain types of customizations (be it an installation or a setup adjustment)?

Comment: docker documentation link is broken